# Find duplicates in nested object

Tags: javascript

Assuming that I have a JS object wich contains other objects inside it, but all of them have the same structure.
I am trying to search inside them for any duplicated values.
For example:

```
{
    {
        id: "123"
        name: "John"
        surname: "Smith"
        phone: "123456789"
    }, 
    {
        id: "456"
        name: "Jack"
        surname: "Jones"
        phone: "9876789123"
    }, 
    {
        id: "789"
        name: "John"
        surname: "Doe"
        phone: "123456789"
    }
}
```

I want to search and find that the property 'phone' with value '123456789' is the same on both objects with ids '123' and '789'.

*Note:* the property/value combination that I am searching for is unknown beforehand.

Comment: *ahem*... altogether now: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the outer structure is a plain `Object`, use an `Array` instead. If you can't change the structure, I'd convert it first.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/3Y2qr/

```
if (!Array.isArray(data))
    data = Object.keys(data)
                 .sort(function(a,b) { return a - b })
                 .map(function(key) { return data[key] })
```

Then you can reduce the set to groups of matches.

```
var groupByPhone = data.reduce(function(found, obj) {
    if (found[obj.phone])
        found[obj.phone].push(obj)
    else
        found[obj.phone] = [obj]
    return found
}, {});

var dupes = Object.keys(groupByPhone)
                  .filter(function(key) {
                      return groupByPhone[key].length > 1
                  })
```

So now `groupByPhone` is an object where the keys are the unique phone numbers, and the values are the objects that have that number.

The  `dupes` will be a list of phone number keys that can be used to lookup groups of duplicate objects in `groupByPhone`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what i was looking for. My main problem was that, as you figured out, the outer structure is an Object and i was manipulating it as an Array.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter` to the rescue !

```
var searchFor = '123456789';

var filteredResult = arrayOfObjects.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.phone === searchFor;
});

console.log( filteredResult );
```

Comment: you can make it faster by avoiding a closure using this: return obj.phone==this;}, searchFor );

Comment: @dandavis It could also be a lot faster if a normal `for` loop is used

Comment: I think the idea is that the match string isn't known, and OP wants to find duplicates based on the `.phone` property. Also, I'm not certain that OP has an actual Array, though if not, one should be used.

Comment: @ian yes, usually for loops are still faster, though not as much faster as they were two years ago. Filter() provides code re-usability that for loops cannot touch, and that often out-weighs raw benchmark performance.

Comment: @squint: [].slice.call(objArrish) enables [].filter() on array-like numbered index object like strings and the literal in the OP.

Comment: @dandavis: That would also require a `.length` property. And you don't need `[].slice.call(obj, ...` first. You could just do `[].filter.call(obj, ...`

Comment: @squint you are right, the match string is unknown. I have tried with another combination of `filter` and i got an error that the object has no method `filter`